# How to disable mouse acceleration on Wayland? (Fedora 28)

Tags: gnome3, mouse, wayland

I tried googling around for a while and all the info I could find is old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways of doing it are (1) use `gsettings` at the command line prompt or use `gnome-tweak-tool`, a graphical tool that may not be installed by default.

**Using `gsettings`:**

To find the current setting, open a terminal window and type this command at the prompt:

```
gsettings   get   org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse   accel-profile
```

The response will be either 'default', 'flat' or 'adaptive'

To change the value to 'flat',

```
gsettings  set  org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse  accel-profile  flat
```

You may want to read the man page for the `gsettings` command.  If you want to see all of the values that can be set with `gsettings`, use this command

```
gsettings list-recursively | sort | more
```

**Gnome tweak tool:**

This tool is not installed by default, but installing it is easy enough.  One way to install it is to use the `dnf` program.  Do this at the command prompt as root:

dnf install gnome-tweak-tool

There are other ways to install the command, too.  Use whatever method works for you.  Then launch the tool from the desktop icons.  The icon for "Tweak Tool" may be found in the "Utilities" group.  If you can't find the icon, you can launch the tool from the command line with `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Launch the tool and select "Keyboard and Mouse" in the left hand column.  Then you can pick the mouse acceleration profile.

**Dconf-Editor**

Okay, there is a third method, but I don't like it.  It acts as a GUI to the `gsettings` command, as far as I can tell.  Root can install it with `dnf install dconf-editor`.  Then as a plain user you must navigate to org->gnome->desktop->peripherals->mouse, and there you will find the same 3 possible values.